# Trunc Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, aplicação-web, java-ee

Tenho a seguinte query a preciso buscar no banco agendamentos de acordo com as datas informadas (data inicial e data final). Digamos que realizei um agendamento para o dia 20/10/19. Se eu tentar buscar esse agendamento informando o dia 20/10/19 nas duas condições, data inicial e data final, ele não me traz nada e o agendamento existe. Se eu tentar buscar informando como data inicial o dia 19/10/19 e como data final a data do agendamento que é dia 20/10/19, ele me traz o agendamento salvo, até aí tudo bem mas também preciso trazer o agendamento informando a mesma data nas duas condições. O que falta ou está errado?

```
        <![CDATA[
            select 
                da.dtAgenda as dtAgenda, 
                to_char(da.dtAgenda, 'DD/MM/YYYY') as dsDataFormatada, 
                da.agendaDonoAgenda.donoAgenda.dsDonoAgenda as dsDonoAgenda,
                da.agendaDonoAgenda.agenda.dsAgenda as dsAgenda,
                da.agendaDonoAgenda.agenda.cdAgenda as cdAgendaSelecionado,
                da.agendaDonoAgenda.donoAgenda.cdDonoAgenda as cdDonoAgendaSelecionado
            from  
                DistribuicaoAgendaModel as da
            where 
                da.agendaDonoAgenda.agenda.cdAgenda = :cdAgenda
                and da.agendaDonoAgenda.agenda.idAtivo = 'S'
                and da.agendaDonoAgenda.agenda.entidade.cdEntidade = :cdEntidade
                and trunc(da.dtAgenda) between :dtInicial and :dtFinal
            group by
                da.dtAgenda, 
                da.agendaDonoAgenda.agenda.dsAgenda,
                da.agendaDonoAgenda.donoAgenda.dsDonoAgenda,
                da.agendaDonoAgenda.agenda.cdAgenda,
                da.agendaDonoAgenda.donoAgenda.cdDonoAgenda
            order by 
                da.dtAgenda, 
                da.agendaDonoAgenda.donoAgenda.dsDonoAgenda             
        ]]>
    </query>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode adicionar condições de igualdade para a data inicial e data final:

```
and ( 
   (trunc(da.dtAgenda) between :dtInicial and :dtFinal) OR
   trunc(da.dtAgenda) = :dtInicial OR 
   trunc(da.dtAgenda) = :dtFinal
)
```